# Is it possible to reference .NET Framework library in a Xamarin.Forms app?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, .net-standard-2.0

I have a Xamarin.Forms project (.NET Standard 2.0 library + Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform 6.0.7)
and I would like to reference a .NET Framework 4.6.1 library.

I added a reference to my Framework library in the .NET Standard 2.0 library, but this result in the error

> Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'Type universe cannot resolve assembly: FrameworkLib, Version=1.0.10735.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.

I tried to add the reference to my FrameworkLib in the UWP project, but it fails with the message:

> Unable to add a reference to project 'FrameworkLib'

Is it possible to add a reference to add a reference to a .Net Framework 4.6.1 library in a Xamarin.Forms app? Do I need a special NuGet package?

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard it seems like it should be compatible? I can reference my UWP project in my FrameworkLib, but not the other way around...

I can reproduce this with empty projects. (VS 2017)

Comment: yea but UWP can't be use on anything but windows.... UWP is another thing like Xamarian.Forms

Comment: Check your installed windows software and see if you have Net 1.0.  I think you are missing Net 1.0.

Comment: @jdweng In C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk I have version 1.1.7 and 2.1.4

Comment: I said : Control Panel : Programs : Program and Features.  It looks like you need framework 3.5 to use framework 1.0.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/on-windows-10.  Sde following for downloads : https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archive.md