# How to use .Net framework library with xamarin forms

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a .Net framework library that I want to reference it in my xamarin forms project.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Xamarin app targets [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard), not .NET Framework. Either change your library to also target .NET Standard, which will allow you to use it in both Xamarin apps and your .NET Framework 4.6 projects, or use another JSON serialization library such as [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json) which already targets .NET Standard.

From Resource: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/127820/target-net-framework-4-6-in-xamarin-forms

Another reference I hope it'll help you:

[Is it possible to reference .NET Framework library in a Xamarin.Forms app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48893655/is-it-possible-to-reference-net-framework-library-in-a-xamarin-forms-app)

Answer (score -1):

Open Visual Studio and right click on your Xamarin Forms project > Add Reference > Browser > Select your library from your file system > OK