# How can i make archive iPA in Visual studio MAC. error occur in latest version

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Package 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

Comment: Please read [ask] before posting.  Your post does not contain an actual question

Comment: The issue is getting for IPA not build using Xamrin form iOS in Mac Os.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message you provided, it lists some supported versions of NETFramework and you are using NETStandard.

So You should change your projecr target framework from **.NETStandard** to **.NETFramework**.

Comment: But how we can change in Xamarin form project framework from NETStandard to .NETFramework.

Comment: This link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57128531/how-to-use-net-framework-library-with-xamarin-forms) may help you.

Comment: Wen xu Li
Yes, it is okay but which to follow to prevent these bugs?

Comment: Use any library to strictly abide by all its requirements.

Comment: Did it solve your problem?

Comment: no i am getting your points.

Comment: wish you success

Comment: Wen xu Li - MSFT pls suggest me how can solved this issue?